# CSS : Is it possible to have a gradient background on the selection pseudo element?

Tags: css, gradient, pseudo-element, linear-gradients

i'm trying to add a gradient background to the selection pseudo element. So far i've tried this bit of code, and it's just returning a white background.

```
    ::-moz-selection { 
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(-45deg, $degrade-min 0%, $degrade-max 100%); /* FF3.6-15 */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(-45deg, $degrade-min 0%,$degrade-max 100%); /* Chrome10-25,Safari5.1-6 */
    background: linear-gradient(135deg, $degrade-min 0%,$degrade-max 100%); /* W3C, IE10+, FF16+, Chrome26+, Opera12+, Safari7+ */
    color:white;
}
::selection { 
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(-45deg, $degrade-min 0%, $degrade-max 100%); /* FF3.6-15 */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(-45deg, $degrade-min 0%,$degrade-max 100%); /* Chrome10-25,Safari5.1-6 */
    background: linear-gradient(135deg, $degrade-min 0%,$degrade-max 100%); /* W3C, IE10+, FF16+, Chrome26+, Opera12+, Safari7+ */
    color:white;
}
```

So i'm wondering if maybe that's just not possible ?

Comment: Do not use edits simply to bump your questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> So i'm wondering if maybe that's just not possible ?

https://drafts.csswg.org/css-pseudo-4/#highlight-styling:

> The following properties apply to the highlight pseudo-elements:
>
> `color`
> `background-color`
> `cursor`
> `caret-color`
> `outline`   and its longhands
> `text-decoration` and its associated properties
> `text-emphasis-color`
> `text-shadow`

Since a gradient is considered an *image* in terms of CSS, the answer is: No, because the `background-image` property is not part of the above list, so *by specification* it is not possible.

Comment: oh right, I didn't know a background was considered as an image! Thank you very much:)